# Passing Structure from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have the following structure in C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) struct SnapRoundingOption
{
    double PixelSize;
    bool IsISR;
    bool IsOutputInteger;
    int KdTrees;
};
```

And this is my function declaration in C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void FaceGenerationDummy(SnapRoundingOption snapOption);
```

This is the corresponding C# code:

```
// I also tried not specifying Pack, but the same error occurred.
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct SnapRoundingOption
{
    public  double PixelSize;
    public bool IsISR;
    public bool IsOutputInteger;
    public int KdTrees;

    public SnapRoundingOption(double pixelSize, bool isISR, bool isOutputInt, int kdTrees)
    {
        PixelSize = pixelSize;
        IsISR = isISR;
        IsOutputInteger = isOutputInt;
        KdTrees = kdTrees;
    }
}

[DllImport("Face.dll")]
public static extern void FaceGenerationDummy(SnapRoundingOption snapRoundingOption);
```

However, when I call the `FaceGenerationDummy` with this test:

```
[Test]
public void DummyTest()
{
    SimpleInterop.FaceGenerationDummy(new SnapRoundingOption(10, true, false, 1));
}
```

I found that KdTrees is 0 in C++, instead of 1 as passed in.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1: I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 32-bit.

Edit 2: Both `sizeof(SnapRoundingOption)` return the same number – 16.

Comment: Are you sure the packing alignment is also 1 in C++?

Comment: I tried both, specify `Pack` and don't specify `Pack`, none which worked.

Comment: @Graviton: Also, does your C++ compiler consider `int` to be 32 bits wide?

Comment: @Mehrdad, I'm using visual studio 2008 on a Windows 7 32 bit machine.

Comment: @Graviton: Ooooh... where's the word "struct" for your `struct`? Is that a typo or is it actually what you wrote?!

Comment: Check out the memory representation of your structure in C++ and use the proper `Pack` and `MarshalAs` attributes/parameters.

Comment: Pack is 8 by default in C/C++, so try specifying 8, (and 4 just in case ... ;). Everything else seems fine to me. Have a look a the memory representation of your struct may help. Good point from Mehrdad.

Comment: @Graviton: Oh, and also try saying `sizeof(SnapRoundingOption)` in both versions and checking if they're the same.

Comment: @Graviton: Wait, just to make sure: You're *not* declaring the C version of `FaceGenerationDummy` inside any `class` or `struct`, right?

Comment: @Graviton: By the way, just a note about your struct: `warning C4091: '__declspec(dllexport)' : ignored on left of 'SnapRoundingOption' when no variable is declared`

Comment: @Mehrdad, no. I don't declare them inside any class or struct. And even if I did, most likely I would get an entry point not found kind of exception.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem here is how you are marshalling the `bool` fields. These are single bytes in C++ and so need to be marshalled so:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SnapRoundingOption
{
    public double PixelSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool IsISR;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool IsOutputInteger;
    public int KdTrees;
}
```

Match this up on the C++ side:

```
struct SnapRoundingOption
{
    double PixelSize;
    bool IsISR;
    bool IsOutputInteger;
    int KdTrees;
};
```

I removed the packing settings so that the structures will have alignment natural to the platform.

You should also make sure that your calling conventions agree. As it stands it looks like the C++ code uses `cdecl`, and the C# code uses `stdcall`. For example

```
[DllImport("Face.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

would align the two sides of the interface.

Comment: @mehrdad Thanks, I like these P/Invoke questions!

Comment: @David: Ditto... they make me think harder. :) (I especially like the COM interface questions... *those* can get really tricky!)

Comment: @Graviton Why didn't you do the C++ part as well? It matters! Anyway, I wrote a test for this and successfully passed this struct in both directions.

Comment: Weren't you saying just a while ago that you weren't a C# programmer? Are you maintaining such an app now that's forced you to learn P/Invoke syntax?

Comment: @David: That's what I suggested 40 minutes ago in my comment :-P. @Graviton: packing alignment should be the same for you in both C++ and C#. It should work with Pack=0 or without it.

Comment: @Jaroslav Jandek Indeed, but I'm afraid you didn't spell it out.

Comment: @Cody It's true, I know next to nothing about C#. Please don't broadcast this dirty secret!!   ;-)

Comment: Amazing, this is the answer; mind to explain how does `#pragma pack(push, 1)` affects the whole packing?

Comment: @David: are you sure about WinAPI using packing alignment 1? MS recommends using the default packing (8) so datatypes are aligned according to their size. Also I have only seen MS using pack=1 for arrays (internally generated)... @Graviton: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx

Comment: @Jaroslav Well, I thought I was sure, but I've just read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22DBGHELP/MINIDUMPWRITEDUMP%22%29;k%28MINIDUMPWRITEDUMP%29;k%28DevLang-%22C++%22%29;k%28TargetOS-WINDOWS%29&rd=true#controlling_structure_packing) which suggests I'm talking nonsense!

Answer (score 5):

[`bool` is **NOT** blittable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx)! Its default marshaling is the Win32 `BOOL` (which is 4 bytes), *not* `bool` (which is 1 byte)!

Comment: +1: Since you stated what bool is marshaled to (A point David Heffernan forgot in his answer :-) )